# SQLite query returns nothing

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this query in SQLite that I want to return a value based on the date passed. The date is in the database as a String. I know that there is data in the database with that date, but it just returns nothing. I dont know why. When I make the query without comparisson parameters, it returns all the data normally, but using the WHERE clause in the query method, it stops returning. Maybe its just a matter of the SQL syntax. Anyways, here is the statement:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "value"}, "current_date = ? ", new String[] {date}, null, null, null);
```

---

**EDIT**

I've made this query in SQLite Database Browser, and it doesn't return any values. Even if its there.

I've seen that this is quite funny and confused. I've tested on Database Browser and also on phone, when I pass the current day, the 'Today' day, it gets the data, but when I pass another day that isnt today, it returns nothing. Very, very weird.

And in Database Browser, I've selected the column that contains the date and it returns only the 'Today' date, even if before there are another dates.

Comment: `new String[] {"_id, value"}` - you probably want `new String[] {"_id", "value"}` instead. If that doesn't solve it, please post what value `date` exactly has and what's in the database.

Comment: both the formats (incoming and in database) are in this format yyyy-mm-dd. I fixed this issued, but didnt solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name was 'current_date' and this is a SQLite function name. So it didn't get the other dates, just the current date.

Comment: Then you either wrote a wrong query in your app or it was just a typo here.in your question,it was Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "value"}, "date = ? ", new String[] {date}, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

if your date is stored in database in format 'dd-mm-yyyy',then try using it like-

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "value"}, "date = ? ", String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY",cal), null, null, null);
```

For other formats,please refer http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html